# keep jquery value after page after press enter key or page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

i want to keep a jquery value for input box value after press enter key or refresh not reload. when click button then set a value of a input box but when page refresh or press enter key then input box value erase. i have uses localStorage but it is not working for me.

here is my html code....

```
<button id="read">set value</button>
<input type="text" id="value">
```

here is my jquery.....

```
$(function(){
       $('#read').on('click', function () {
           var someVarName = "value";
           localStorage.setItem("someVarName", someVarName);
           var someVarName = localStorage.getItem("someVarName");
           $('#value').val(someVarName)
       })
    });
```

Comment: Any error in console?\

Comment: are you redirecting to the same domain ? or the redirecting is happening to different website

Comment: Instead of "someVarName" Can you please mention proper variable name which you have used in your page. That might be a possibility for issue .

Answer (score 1):

Below is the working code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#read').on('click', function () {
           var someVarName = "value";
           localStorage.setItem("someVarName", someVarName);
           var someVarName = localStorage.getItem("someVarName");
           $('#value').val(someVarName)
       });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="read">set value</button>
<input type="text" id="value">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I delete it when for second refresh/ a new request made?